# Can not close FB session after it is open once. iOS5/6

Tags: ios, facebook

I can open a FB session, then I close it, however the next time i hit this code, it skips right by the user login screen (io5) and already has me logged in. How do I make sure that I re/initiate the FB login screen each time? I tried to close the session before I even opened it, but that did not work either.

```
[self closeFacebookSession];  // close the session so we should get login screen, but we do not!

 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"email",
                            nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                          [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                      }];
}

- (void)closeFacebookSession {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```